# OnCreateView called multiple times / Working with ActionBar and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I switched part of my App from Activities to Fragments so that I can use the neat ActionBar tabs.

However, after completing the transition I ran into an issue: whenever I switch to another tab, that Fragment gets created all over again. Both onCreate and onCreateView get called every time I get to a tab.

I have 4 tabs, each of which is meant to open one of these fragments:

```
Fragment ShopFragment = new WebActivity();
Fragment SearchFragment = new SearchActivity(context);
Fragment StoreFragment = new StoreLocatorActivity(context, this);
Fragment BlogsFragment = new BlogsActivity(context, this);
```

Here's my code for the listener:

```
    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        public Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.hide(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {          

        }

    }
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does anyone know how I could handle this please?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you call [FragmentTransaction.replace(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29), Android will effectively perform a sequence of [FragmentTransaction.remove(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#remove%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29) (for all Fragments currently added to that container) and [FragmentTransaction.add(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) (for your supplied Fragment). Removing a Fragment from the `FragmentManager` will cause the Fragment to be destroyed and its state will no longer be managed. Most noticeably, when you re-add the Fragment all of the views will have been reset. Note: since you are reusing the same Fragment instance, the Fragment will still keep the value any instance variables.

One solution to this problem would be to use [FragmentTransaction.detach(Fragment)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29) and [FragmentTransaction.attach(Fragment)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29) when switching. This will cause the Fragment views to be recreated (`onDestroyView()` & `onCreateView()` will be called), but the instance state bundle will be saved and given back to you between calls and so the view state can be maintained. This is the approach taken by [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) when it tries to switch between Fragments.

Alternatively, you could allow the Fragments to be destroyed, but maintain their saved state for them independently. This would use less memory, at the expense of a slower switching time. Methods of note would be [FragmentManager.saveFragmentInstanceState(Fragment)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#saveFragmentInstanceState%28android.app.Fragment%29) and [FragmentManager.setInitialSavedState(Fragment.SavedState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setInitialSavedState%28android.app.Fragment.SavedState%29), in conjuction with adding/removing. This is the approach taken by [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).

You can have a look at the [source for FragmentPagerAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#FragmentPagerAdapter) and the [source for FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java#FragmentStatePagerAdapter) for implementation hints.

Comment: This is a workaround. onCreate and onCreateView are still getting called and saving states require much work. Isn't there a way to just keep the already painted view of wach fragment and just replace them? Why repaint them all over again?

Comment: Hi i'm using ActionBar Tabs and using attach and detach! Can you please explain with some sample code how can i save instance state when switching to other tab and then maintaining the state when coming back to tab! Thanks

Comment: @kilaka Can you please explain how you get the `saving state` working?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar - don't know. I use show/hide - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033244/435605

Comment: @kilaka but detach and attach are more efficient way than show and hide. I guess!

Comment: @antonyt Can you please help?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar create a question and describe what you have tried so far

Comment: @antonyt I have solved it myself :) Anyway i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 12):

There is the [show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#show%28android.app.Fragment%29)/[hide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29) option just so the fragments would not need to be repainted/recreated and the `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` won't be reinvoked.