# ViewPager does not refresh after replacing fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a List of fragments which i can open in my navbar with:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, l_Fragment).commit();
```

The fragments are all from the same type -> `CDMBasicMovieFragment extends Fragment`

Inside this fragment i have a viewpager which i call with `getFragmentManager()`. And here i have the problem. The first fragment is fine but after replacing the first fragment, the viewpager is empty. Then i changed `getFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()`. Now all fragments are fine. But only 1 time. After replacing back to the first fragment i have the same problem. What am i doing wrong?

**Edit1:**

My view hierarchy:

- Activity

  - CDMBasicMovieFragment 1

    - ViewPager

      - CDMMovieListFragment
  - CDMBasicMovieFragment 2

    - ViewPager

      - CDMMovieListFragment
  - CDMBasicMovieFragment 3

    - ViewPager

      - CDMMovieListFragment

**Edit2:**

I tried to create unique ids for the fragments and used them on replace but i already have the same problem:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, l_Fragment, uniqueFragmentTag).commit();
```

**Edit3:**

I found a possible solution:
[OnCreateView called multiple times / Working with ActionBar and Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201695/oncreateview-called-multiple-times-working-with-actionbar-and-fragments)
I tried everything from this link. I already have the same problem... Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

After a intensive debug session ;) i found this:

When loading the first `CDMMovieListFragment` FragmentPagerAdapter's `instantiateItem` is called and checks if there's already a fragment. It's not thats why it internally calls

`mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment, makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));`

When i replace the `CDMBasicMovieFragment` which includes the fragmentpageradapter (inside is the added `CDMMovieListFragment`) and try to load the second `CDMBasicMovieFragment` then it's still the same fragmentmanager.

FragmentPagerAdapter's `instantiateItem` is called and found the old `CDMMovieListFragment`. Now it calls `mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);` instead. I think here's the problem. But im so confused...

Comment: Is this relevant to your situation?
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
// must have OffscreenPageLimit set because default is 1 and we have 3 tabs. If one is not available off screen when a loader finishes it will crash otherwise


    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

Comment: I dont want to change the fragment inside the viewpager. I want to replace the fragment which includes the viewpager. Check my edit. I added my view hierarchy.

Comment: I see.  That is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved my problem.

Now i always replace the `CDMBasicMovieFragment` like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, CDMBasicMovieFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

On calling the FragmentPagerAdapter's constructor i changed `getFragmentManager` to `getChildFragmentManager`.

I thought i can create all fragment one time and just replace them if i click on the item of the navigationbar (drawner). But the `replace` will remove the fragment which was created one time and when i want to replace the removed fragment again, it's not there. That's why i got an empty viewpager.

Comment: great. I had same problem like you and now solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code snippet, In your custom pager adapter:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Then in your Activity containing the ViewPager:

```
final MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          ... anything you may need to do to handle pager state ...
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //this line will force all pages to be loaded fresh when changing between fragments
     }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed... Same problem

Comment: had to do this on a specific fragment to force reload. works but introduces a bit of a delay.